# Qt: Delete an item from QListWidget and from the computer

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I would like to delete an item from QListWidget and from the computer.

I know how to delete an item from the computer using:

```
listWidget->takeItem(listWidget->row(listWidget->currentItem()));
```

But I don't know how to delete these items from the computer. I add it using the path like that:

```
listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("\\..\\..\\...jpg"),"xxxxxxxx"));
```

So I think it's possible to delete it if we get the path of the item.
The thing is that I don't know how to get the path of the item.
I tried this:

```
QFileInfo info(listWidget->currentItem()->icon().name());
QString str= info.absoluteFilePath();
```

or this:

```
QFileInfo info(listWidget->currentItem()->text());
QString str= info.absoluteFilePath();
```

But I only get the path of the name file "xxxxxxxx" chosen while adding the item. This path is in the build folder `"/.../...Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2010_32bit_OpenGL-Debug"`.

Does anyone know how to delete an item from the computer please?

Comment: Do you even need the full path? I mean are all the file names that you put in your QListWidget in the applications current working folder. I mean a simple QDir dir; dir.remove(filename); should work if the file is in the current working folder.

Comment: You may set ay userData (for example - full path) to your item, when you add it. And use it when you need to delete real file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately no, files can be anywhere. So yes I need the full path. I need the path `"\\..\\..\\...jpg"` sent at the line `listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("\\..\\..\\...jpg"),"xxxxxxxx"));`. But I don't know maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: Then you need to store the full path in the QListWidget. userData is the way you do that.

Comment: Or do all files have an icon that is in the folder containing the file? So you would get the path (with filename of icon stripped) of the icon and append the filename to that.

Comment: Ok thank you I made it! Thanks also to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136818/can-i-store-some-user-data-in-every-item-of-a-qlistwidget]